# Axios - Sending Nested JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, axios

I have a web page that is using the [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) Http Client. In my web page, I'm getting my location using the [browser's geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) feature. When my location is obtained, I want to send that location, along with other data. To do this, I've built data object like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position) { 
    var data = {
      id: 1,
      user:'me',
      location: position
    };
  })
;
```

I then try to send the data via Axios like this:

```
axios.put('/my-endpoint', data, options)
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(res);
    })
;
```

I get a successful response back from this request. However, it's a false positive. When I look at the logs, it's weird. I can see that the `location` property is an empty object. So, I did a console.log in the browser and I can see that `location` is properly set. But when I send it via Fiddler, I notice that it's not there. It's just an empty object when it goes across the wire. How?

I suspect there is some setting or something else I have to do to send a nested JavaScript object over the network. But I don't see anything. What am I doing wrong? I've made a basic JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/04sjfgf9/) with this code..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your variable `data` is out of scope when you are trying to send it. In the example you've given data is local variable of that closure which means it is destroyed when the callback completes. To get around this you need to declare `data` outside of that function where it will be visible to axios as well. You can still assign to it inside the callback, you have to actually but you should declare it above.

Comment: the variable data is in scope. It looks out of scope because of how I phrased the question. But, in my actual code the `axios` call happens right after the `var data` line.

Comment: Is it only for the `location` property? Are `user` and `id` going through ok?

Comment: It's only the `location` property that is showing this behavior. `user` and `id` are going through ok.